# React Native - Image isn't cleared when navigating

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-listview

I use React Native's Navigator for routing and ListView to show image group, and I use Android. When I trigger navigation, image(s) don't leave page and it blinks as seen below.

[image]

**Render functions**

```
_renderRow (rowData){
    return (
       <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>this._getCampaigns(rowData)}>
           <Image style={{width: 120, height: 120}}
              source={{uri: rowData.logo, scale: 1}}/>
           </TouchableWithoutFeedback>)
}

render() {
   return (<View style={styles.container}>
      <ListView dataSource={this.state.imageList} 
       contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
       renderRow={(rowData)=> this._renderRow(rowData)}/>
   </View>);
}
```

**Styles**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1
        },
        list: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            flexWrap: 'wrap'
        }
});
```

What could be the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Does "second screen" have `flex: 1` ?

Comment: Yes it has `flex: 1`

Comment: Then my last option is to disable the remote debugger, if you're running it, because it seems the transition is really slow.

Comment: I don't use it right now. After setting backgroundColor style in second page, weirdness looks closely resolved. But, I wonder to get reason.

Comment: Yes, sometimes backgroundColor can have weird effects like filling an empty View that was being replaced by other components.

Comment: It might just be the scene transition, try changing to something else and see if you still have the same issue.